# How to get used of those two dictionary files

Tags: c#, dictionary, translation, encode

I have two strange looking files, I know that these are the dictionary one seems to be german and the other czech and they may have connection between the files.

[czech or german 1](https://www.file-upload.net/download-88888888888888/del.html)

[czech or german 2](https://www.file-upload.net/download-88888888888888/del.html)

Now I want to encode these dictionary files, so that I can use them in my private program, because I dont find any reliable dictionary that I can buy or download for free, which contains german and czech in a way I could use it somehow in the program.

How to get closer to my aim ?

Comment: Why do you need encryption?

Comment: actually I dont know wether these files are somehow encrypted, because I dont see any sense in that file structure,

Comment: This has nothing to do with encryption, please remove the tag.

Comment: what kind of encoding could it be?